# Why can I see comments but no field or button to reply to them in Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm helping someone with a document and have used Track Changes in LibreOffice to create a comment.  I then saved as .docx again and sent it back.

The person on the other end* sees my comment but, unlike all the videos and screenshots I've come across so far, there is no Reply field or button beneath the comment.

Why might this be?

*Using  Microsoft® Word 2021 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148) 64 Bit

[image: reply-less comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the document is in "Viewing" mode. In this mode, the document cannot be edited, thus no need for the Reply button to be shown.

[image]

Change it to "Editing" mode, then the Reply button will be shown again.

[image]

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks!  I think this behavior stands in contrast to Google Docs, where either you can see and reply to comments, or you can't see them at all.